# How does EOSBET token mining work?

Tags: gambling

I've read that there are people "mining" the EOSBET tokens by playing the EOS casino game. How does one do this "mining" and what is the payout?

Answer (score 1):

As per the EOSBET website:

> Currently, we are airdropping BET tokens at a rate of 20:1 for our
>   bettors. This means that for every 20 EOS wagered you will receive 1
>   BET token. These tokens grant you dividends for life, and there is a
>   fixed supply of 88,000,000 tokens in existence.

As for the dividends:

> BET Tokens grant you dividend each second. All game profit is
>   distributed to token holders, so the more BET you own, the more EOS
>   you recieve!

To claim the dividends, log in to the website with Scatter and click on the "Claim Dividends" button at the top of the screen

Source: https://eosbet.io/dividends

Comment: how can you just buy more bet tokens?

Comment: I don't think you can. Only through playing on their website